# Is it possible to use more than one tab bar view controller in one application?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

My client want multiple tab bar view controllers in their app. I know it's not good for user experience but i just follow the order. The problem is, I already put 2 tab bar view controllers but it got some weird problem that when I switch to second tab bar view controller, it keep showing the first one. Is it because of navigation controller? How to fix it?

Comment: LOL, forget about it. That app won't be approved by the Apple Review team.

Comment: BTW, this app for internal use, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a "show detail" segue to transition from the first tab bar to the second tab bar but if you do it of this way you will have to add a another "show detail" segue to come back to the first tab bar. If you use this solution be careful with the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
Create one tab bar controller and set UIViewController's subclass as it's "tab".
Then in this viewController instantiate new tabBarController and add tabBarController's view to viewController's view

```
tabBarC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
tabBarC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
tabBarC.view.frame = vc.view.bounds;
[vc.view addSubview:tabBarC.view];
```

Sorry i can't check if it will work or not, but that's the way i would give a shot.

Comment: tabBarC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        tabBarC view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
        tabBarC.view.frame = vc.view.bounds
        vc.view.addSubview(self.view)

this would be same code in swift.